# Update MySQL: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 8

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, swing, jdbc

Not to sure what I am missing here but nothing seems to be working for me. I tried several approaches and none seemed to work. Any idea?

Here is my Code:

```
btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String pid = textIDField.getText();
        String fn = textFNameField.getText();
        String ln = textLNameField.getText();
        String add = addressField.getText();
        String city = cityField.getText();
        String phone = phoneField.getText();
        String mid = medIDField.getText();

        try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("dbinfo");
            String query = "UPDATE Patient SET PatID=?,FirstName=?,LastName=?,Address=?,City=?,Phone=?,MedID=? WHERE PatID=? AND MedID=?";

            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, pid);
            pst.setString(2, fn );
            pst.setString(3, ln );
            pst.setString(4, add );
            pst.setString(5, city );
            pst.setString(6, phone );
            pst.setString(7, mid );

            pst.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Patient Updated");
            pst.close();

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why didn't you supply a value for parameters 8 and 9 (the values in the where clause)?

Comment: How many `?` do you have in the SQL? **9**. How many parameters are you setting? **7**. Which part of error message "No value specified for parameter 8" is unclear?

Comment: You're expecting it to be smart enough to know that pid and mid are used twice.  You need to supply it both times.  Really, why are updating those values when they aren't going to change?

Comment: Thanks for hitting me in the head. I corrected both the parameters and the misuse of my id's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please you have not set the values for the last two parameter so check below

```
 try{
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("dbinfo");
                String query = "UPDATE Patient SET  
          PatID=?,FirstName=?,LastName=?,Address=?,City=?,Phone=?,MedID=? ` `WHERE PatID=? AND MedID=?";

                PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.setString(1, pid);
                pst.setString(2, fn );
                pst.setString(3, ln );
                pst.setString(4, add );
                pst.setString(5, city );
                pst.setString(6, phone );
                pst.setString(7, mid );
                 pst.setString(8, mid );//this last two
                pst.setString(9, pid);

                pst.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Patient Updated");
                pst.close();

            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```