# Insert Select & Insert into single query in java

Tags: java, mysql, select, insert

I am creating a billing application. I want to insert same data into two different tables simultaneously in mySQL. Can anyone tell me what should be the query for it. My task is first insert data into calculationinfo table and insert same data into salesinfo table then select all from calculation table. I m trying this but getting SQL syntax error.
here's my query

```
"Insert into calculationinfo (`date`,`prod_name`, `prod_amount`, `total_amount`,`user`, `Gtotal`) values(?,?,?,?,?,?) INSERT INTO salesinfo (`date`,`prod_name`, `prod_amount`, `total_amount`,`user`, `Gtotal`) SELECT * From calculationinfo"
```

I m using java language. Here's the stackprint

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT salesinfo `date`,`prod_name`, `prod_amount`, `total_amount`,`user`, `Gtot' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2487)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1197)
at Restaurant.Calculation.item_tblMouseClicked(Calculation.java:323)
at Restaurant.Calculation.access$600(Calculation.java:34)
at Restaurant.Calculation$7.mouseClicked(Calculation.java:259)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: You're missing the word `INTO` in your query.

Comment: I have used INTO both the time while inserting, where did I miss that word?

Comment: According to your stack trace, you missed it in `INSERT salesinfo`

Comment: I put into keyword in it, but still, it gives me the same error.

Comment: It can't do.  It might give you a different error, but it won't be exactly the same error.

Comment: Also, there are a lot of differences between the query you say you are using vs the query in your stack trace.

Comment: my basic task is to insert same data into two tables simultaneously. Can you please help me about the query for this?

Comment: You should separate your statements by a `;`.

Comment: Now i add this query  "String sql2 = "Insert into calculationinfo (`date`,`prod_name`, `prod_amount`, `total_amount`,`user`, `Gtotal`) values(?,?,?,?,?,?); INSERT INTO salesinfo (`date`,`prod_name`, `prod_amount`, `total_amount`,`user`, `Gtotal`) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";  But now i m getting this error  "java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 7"

Comment: I want to add similar data into two tables

Comment: @Mohammad_Quanit see this Answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014817/update-mysql-java-sql-sqlexception-no-value-specified-for-parameter-8

Comment: by the link i provided you above.. you are not mapping the parameters  with values correctly or completely. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Auto Close resources like as

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("Insert into calculationinfo (`date`,`prod_name`, `prod_amount`, `total_amount`,`user`, `Gtotal`) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)") {

        //Set Data here     

        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    // stmt is auto closed here, even if SQLException is thrown


    try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO salesinfo (`date`,`prod_name`, `prod_amount`, `total_amount`,`user`, `Gtotal`) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?,?,?)");
       //set same data above here
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to separate these two queries with a terminator.

```
"Insert into calculationinfo"+ 
"(`date`,`prod_name`, `prod_amount`, `total_amount`,`user`, `Gtotal`) "+ 
"values(?,?,?,?,?,?);"+ 
"INSERT INTO salesinfo"+ 
"(`date`,`prod_name`, `prod_amount`,`total_amount`,`user`, `Gtotal`) "+
"values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

This will help you out with your query. what i did above is appended the string after formatting the query in readable mode.

Note: Also look as i have passed the values to the second table same as you passed values to the first table. This will work too. :).

`Insert into table1 Select * from table2` will insert all the rows of table1 into table2 which will mess up your data.

Comment: now i m getting this exception java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 7

Comment: First of all i feel pity for the person who down-voted this answer out of jealousy. Second, you need to pass the input from user to the `values(UserInput1, UserInput2)` as you usually do in Java. I don't know how java works with data insertion though.